# ComboBox doesn't load users

Tags: c#, winforms, datasource

```
private void LoadUsersToComboBox()
{
    comboBox1.DataSource = null;
    comboBox1.DataSource = peopleRepo.FindAllPeople(); /*Returns IQueryable<People>*/
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";            
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    CreateNewPerson();            
    LoadUsersToComboBox();
}

private void CreateNewPerson()
{
    if (textBox2.Text != String.Empty)
    {
        Person user = new Person()
        {
            Name = textBox2.Text
        };

        peopleRepo.Add(user);
        peopleRepo.Save();
    }            
}
```

I'd like the combobox to display a list of users, after every save. So, someone creates a new user and it should display in the combobox right after that. This isn't working, no new users are added, only the initial 'load' seems to work.

Comment: Three things - 1. you don't need the initial `comboBox1.DataSource = null;` 2. is the call to `peopleRepo.FindAllPeople();` synchronous? and 3. what happens if you remove the call to `CreateNewPerson();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource.

```
private void LoadUsersToComboBox()
{
    // comboBox1.DataSource = null; // No need for this

    comboBox1.DataSource = peopleRepo.FindAllPeople().ToList(); /*Returns IQueryable<People>*/
}
```

Don't reassign the DisplayMember & The ValueMember every refresh, just once,

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
    LoadUsersToComboBox()
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll accept this as solution when timer is over.

Comment: @ Sergio Tapia: Welcome, and let me know the result.