# Comboboxes only load when selecting the second items and below

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

This is really strange. I want to select a State and load Cities from that State in another combobox.

It's working EXCEPT when selecting the first item in the combobox:

Here's my entire class. The `if` statement in the `selectedIndexChanged` is to make sure that something is selected. The problem is that if I set that to `cmbState.SelectedIndex >= 0` then an exception is raised because on initial load the comboBox doesn't has a `.State` variable there and not a `.Value`.

I don't know if this makes any sense.

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadDepartmentsToComboBox();
}

private void LoadCitiesToComboBox(long StateID)
{
    cmbCity.DataSource = null;
    CityRepository cityRepo = new CityRepository();
    cmbCity.DataSource = cityRepo.FindAllCities().Where(c => c.IDState == StateID);
    cmbCity.DisplayMember = "Name";
    cmbCity.ValueMember = "ID";
}

private void LoadDepartmentsToComboBox()
{
    cmbState.DataSource = null;
    StateRepository stateRepo = new StateRepository();
    cmbState.DataSource = stateRepo.FindAllStates();
    cmbState.DisplayMember = "Name";
    cmbState.ValueMember = "ID";
}

private void cmbState_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbState.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        LoadCitiesToComboBox(Convert.ToInt64(cmbState.SelectedValue));
    }
}
```

If I **do** use `cmbState.SelectedIndex >= 0` then I receive this exception:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'DocumentScannerDanyly.State' to type
>   'System.IConvertible'.'System.IConvertible'.

When I **don't** use the `SelectedIndex >= 0` and use plain old `>0` then everything works except when selected the first item, which does nothing; understandably because it doesn't take the first item into account.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: The FindAllCities(), FindAllStates() methods return their respective IQueryable<City/State>. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't assign the Display member & the Value member in each load, just assign them once in constructor for example.
2. add ToList() to the result which will assign to DataSource,

> Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource.

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051939/combobox-doesnt-load-users/4051997#4051997).

Comment: I combined this answer with removing the .DataSource = null from my code and now it works very well. Thanks a lot for your help.